# Where is the location of Jquery tablesorter css class for "first", "last" and "pagesize"

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using jquery tablesorter with tablesorterPager. I want to add the buttons "first"," "last" and "pagesize" but I cannot find the location for these classes. I have added the code below

```
    /images/first.png" class="first"
    /images/last.png" class="last"
    class="pagesize".
 
    tablesorterPager({
                positionFixed: false,
                container: $("#pager"),
                updateArrows: true,
                cssNext: '.next',
                cssPrev: '.prev',
                cssFirst: '.first',
                cssLast: '.last',
                cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
                cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
                cssDisabled: 'disabled',             
                cssErrorRow: 'tablesorter-errorRow'
             

            });
```

Comment: Can you provide a link (CDN/web/github) to the "tablesorter" that you are using?  A quick google shows >200,000 results for "jquery tablesorter".

Comment: I am using the link from "https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Download"  Version: 2.31.3

Comment: Also these two jquery jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js and jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js